# Django Form Wizard With Fieldsets

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm using the Django Form Wizard (From 1.8 located in `formtools`) to split a form into multiple steps.

This works fine and all. But I'm interested in making fieldsets in my form and splitting my form into multiple different groups on each page. [A good example would be this](https://www.hittamaklare.se/registrera/1).

[I found a module](https://github.com/carljm/django-form-utils) called `django-form-utils` that replaces the `forms.Form` with a `BetterForm` class, where you can specify fieldsets. The problem with this is that in my template, The Wizard wants me to use `{{wizard.form}}`, but with `BetterForm` I'm forced to use `{{form.fieldsets}}`.

Maybe someone know a way to use them together and make them compatible? Or perhaps someone know another way of using Fieldsets with Form Wizard.

I'm interested in any answer that can tell me how to use Fieldsets with Form Wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I feel stupid. This was way easier than I expected. For some reason I completely misunderstood the `{{wizard.form}}` functionality.

To use the `fieldsets` from `django-form-utils`. Just use `{{wizard.form.fieldsets}}`.